# How to divide list of lists by another list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, floating-point, division

I have `q = [[7,2,3],[4,5,6]]` and `r=[[6,1,2],[3,4,5]]`. I need to divide q by the corresponding elements in r. (i.e. `[[7/6,2/1,3/2],[4/3,5/4,6/5]]`)

Output needed B = [[1.16,2,1.5],[1.33,1.25,1.2]]

Code:

`B= [[float(j)/float(i) for j in q] for i in r]`.

However, I keep getting an error : TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number. I have imported division from future. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to iterate over the *values in the sublists*, not the sublists themselves. Right now you're trying to convert lists into floats...

Comment: numpy will do that for you!

Comment: I am not comfortable using numphy, Any suggestions for this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [*zip*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) for bring together the sublists pairwise and then use it again to bring together the corresponding numerators and denominators:

```
>>> q = [[7,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> r = [[6,1,2],[3,4,5]]
>>> [[n/d for n, d in zip(subq, subr)] for subq, subr in zip(q, r)]
[[1.1666666666666667, 2.0, 1.5], [1.3333333333333333, 1.25, 1.2]]
```

Comment: Thanks. How does this work for an integer divided by one element in a list of lists? I tried doing it in this (http://stackoverflow.com/q/39969884/6820344) question I posted. Under "Failed Output", you can see that it does not allow one to do this type of division.

Comment: If Python 2, you need `[[float(n)/d for n, d in zip(subq, subr)] for subq, subr in zip(q, r)]`

Comment: For Python 2, add ``from __future__ import division``.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
>>> out=[]
>>> for s1, s2 in zip(q, r):
...    inner=[]
...    for n, d in zip(s1, s2):
...       inner.append(float(n)/d)
...    out.append(inner)
... 
>>> out
[[1.1666666666666667, 2.0, 1.5], [1.3333333333333333, 1.25, 1.2]]
```

Or, use numpy:

```
>>> q=[[7.,2.,3.],[4.,5.,6.]]
>>> r=[[6.,1.,2.],[3.,4.,5.]]
>>> np.array(q)/np.array(r)
array([[ 1.16666667,  2.        ,  1.5       ],
       [ 1.33333333,  1.25      ,  1.2       ]])
```

Or, if you have int literals:

```
>>> q=[[7,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> r=[[6,1,2],[3,4,5]]
>>> np.array(q, dtype=float)/np.array(r)
array([[ 1.16666667,  2.        ,  1.5       ],
       [ 1.33333333,  1.25      ,  1.2       ]])
```